# differential forms- $\omega $ closed but not exact

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

let be 
$$ \omega= |x|^{-3} \left(x_1 dx_2 \wedge dx_3+x_2dx_3 \wedge dx_1 + x_3dx_1 \wedge dx_2\right) $$ 
and $G:= \mathbb{R}^3 \backslash \{ 0 \} $

I want to prove, that $ \omega$ is closed, but not exact

That $ \omega $ is closed, I can prove it by looking if $ d\omega =0 $

But how can I prove it's not exact?

I know that a continous 2-form is exact in $G$ if there exists a 1-Form $y$ so, that $\omega = dy $
how can I show there doesn't exist such $y$?

---

Edit:
Showing $\int_S \omega \neq 0 $

Where $S$ is the unitsphere
Set $r=1$ and set
$$x_1= \sin \phi \cos \theta $$
$$x_2= \sin \phi \sin \theta$$
$$x_3= \cos \phi $$

$ \theta=[0, 2\pi], \phi=[0, \pi]$

then $ dx_1 \wedge dx_2 = -\sin \phi \cos \phi d\theta \wedge d\phi $

$ dx_2 \wedge dx_3 = -\sin^2 \phi \cos \theta d\theta \wedge d\phi $

$ dx_3 \wedge dx_1 = -\sin^2 \phi \sin \theta d \theta \wedge d\phi $

Putting in the equation:
$$ \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^{ \pi} |x| ( \sin \phi \cos \theta - \sin^2 \phi \cos \theta ~d \theta \wedge d\ \phi \\+ \sin \phi \sin \theta -\sin^2 \phi \sin \theta ~d\theta \wedge d\phi + \cos \phi -\sin \phi \cos \phi~ d \theta \wedge d\phi $$

what do I put for $x$ ?
I don't know how to solve the integral
thank you for any help!

Comment: The first thing to try would be to integrate it on the unit sphere; if the result is not zero, then $\omega$ is not exact.

Comment: @AlexProvost What does it mean to integrate the unit sphere?

Comment: @MathOverview I said to "integrate **it** on the unit sphere", meaning the 2-form.

Comment: @AlexProvost But why integrate in the unitary sphere and not in $ G $?

Comment: @AlexProvost I have a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065317/every-differential-form-omega-of-degree-1-in-the-sphere-sm-subset-mathbbr)

Comment: On the unit sphere, $|x| = 1$. By the way, this reduces to the standard volume form on $S^2$, so you expect the integral to yield the surface area, $4\pi$.

Comment: I've edited to change `sin` to `\sin` (and similarly for other trig functions). It makes it much more readable.

Comment: "What do I put for $x$?" Well, $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$, for which you have formulas.

Comment: @AlexProvost thank you, you helped me well ! I have calculated the integral a few times now, are you sure that it's not $-4 \pi $?

Comment: @MathOverview I don't understand your question. 2-forms can only be integrated on surfaces, not three-dimensional regions like $G$ here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch to spherical coordinates and integrate $\omega$ on the unit sphere $r = 1$. Let $\theta,\phi$ denote the azimuth and polar angles, respectively; then $$dx = \cos \theta \sin \phi \, dr - \sin \theta \sin \phi \, d\theta + \cos\theta \cos \phi \, d\phi$$
$$ dy = \sin \theta \sin \phi \, dr + \cos \theta \sin\phi \, d\theta + \sin \theta \cos \phi \, d\phi $$
$$dz = \cos \phi \, dr - \sin\phi \, d\phi$$

and after some algebra we find that $\omega = \sin\phi \, d\phi \wedge d\theta$. Hence $$\int_{S^2} \omega = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \sin \phi \, d\phi \, d\theta = 2\cdot 2\pi = 4\pi.$$

This is the expected answer, namely the surface area of the sphere, as $\omega$ restricted to $S^2$ is precisely the volume form induced by that of $\mathbb R^3$. And since the integral is not zero, $\omega$ cannot be exact, lest Stoke's theorem be violated.